# Javascript/HTML "error": "Please use POST request" when using dropdown selection with case/switch statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a drop down list with each value corresponding to a case/switch statement which will display a grid of text input fields with a submit button. However it doesn't seem to work. Please check the fiddle or the code below.

http://jsfiddle.net/7PEhv/3/

```
    <html>
    <body>
      <FORM NAME=frmOne>
      <select name='myfield' onchange='this.form.submit()'>
        <option value = 2>2x2</option>
        <option value = 3>3x3</option>
        <option value = 4>4x4</option>
        <option value = 5>5x5</option>
      </select>
      </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      size = document.frmOne.myfield.value

      switch (size)
      {
        case 2:
          <input type="integer" name="name1"/>
          <input type="integer" name="name2"/>
          <input type="integer" name="name3"/>
          <input type="integer" name="name4"/>
          <input type="button" Value="Add Into Array" 
          onclick="insert(this.form.name.value), insert2(this.form.name2.value);"/>
        break;
        case 3:
          <input type="integer" name="name1"/>
          <input type="integer" name="name2"/>
          <input type="integer" name="name3"/>
          <input type="integer" name="name4"/>
          <input type="integer" name="name5"/>
          <input type="integer" name="name6"/>
          <input type="integer" name="name7"/>
          <input type="integer" name="name8"/>
          <input type="integer" name="name9"/>
          <input type="button" Value="Add Into Array" 
          onclick="insert(this.form.name.value), insert2(this.form.name2.value);"/>
       break;
       case 4:
         <input type="integer" name="name1"/>
         <input type="integer" name="name2"/>
         <input type="integer" name="name3"/>
         <input type="integer" name="name4"/>
         <input type="integer" name="name5"/>
         <input type="integer" name="name6"/>
         <input type="integer" name="name7"/>
         <input type="integer" name="name8"/>
         <input type="integer" name="name9"/>
         <input type="integer" name="name10"/>
         <input type="integer" name="name11"/>
         <input type="integer" name="name12"/>
         <input type="integer" name="name13"/>
         <input type="integer" name="name14"/>
         <input type="integer" name="name15"/>
         <input type="integer" name="name16"/>
         <input type="button" Value="Add Into Array" 
         onclick="insert(this.form.name.value), insert2(this.form.name2.value);"/>

       break;
       default:
         document.write("Pick a selection");
       }
    </script>  

   </body>
 </html>​
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear...use `POST` instead of `GET`. I'm guessing you have an ajax call in there somewhere? Can we see the source for `insert()` and `insert2()`? And you should use semi-colons if you want to execute multiple statements (function calls), not commas.

Comment: You have to provide more information, your code is very strange and it's not clear what you are trying to accomplish here. Why do you need to submit a form every time selection changes on your dropdown? Your code inside switch statements doesn't make sense, it's not a valid JavaScript. Are you just trying to display some input boxes when user changes selection?

Comment: @Ilya Volodin yes, all i want is the user to select the grid size of input boxed and then i'm saving the inputs into an array via the insert() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly guessed what you need here's the code that you require: http://jsfiddle.net/uJABa/5/ You will need to tweak it a bit, to have insert function successfully execute, but I think you can get the idea from the code.

```
function showBoxes(select)
{
   var selectedValue = $(select).find('option:selected').val();
      switch (selectedValue)
      {
        case "2":
          $("#grid").html('<input type="integer" name="name1"/><input type="integer" name="name2"/><input type="integer" name="name3"/><input type="integer" name="name4"/><input type="button" id="insertButton" Value="Add Into Array"/>');
          break;
        case "3":
          $("#grid").html('<input type="integer" name="name1"/><input type="integer" name="name2"/><input type="integer" name="name3"/><input type="integer" name="name4"/><input type="integer" name="name5"/><input type="integer" name="name6"/><input type="integer" name="name7"/><input type="integer" name="name8"/><input type="integer" name="name9"/><input id="insertButton" type="button" Value="Add Into Array"/>');
          break;
        default:
          console.log("Select valid value");
          break;
      }
   $("#insertButton").click(insert);
}

function insert() {}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's pretty much what i was trying to accomplish. Just going to read through it to get an understanding of where i went totally wrong. Very much appreciated your help.

Answer (score 3):

You're seeing a JSFiddle-specific error. When you change the value of the dropdown box, the form submits (as you've told it to), and this submission is what triggers the JSFiddle error (you can't submit forms on JSFiddle, because there is no server to receive them). If you want to actually do something in JavaScript with the new value of the drop, you should not be telling it to submit itself when the value is changed (or you should cancel the event with JavaScript).

Also, the JavaScript you've written is invalid, you've embedded HTML in it which is not allowed (it would need to be quoted in a string and added using DOM methods).

Comment: ah right ok. i have removed the submit of the form. I'll try figure out how to get the case statement to display the text inputs.